# re-organize divs with responsive design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am wondering how i could re-organize my header using responsive design.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">NAME</div>
    <div class="span6">123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789</div>
    <div class="span3">AVATAR</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks as i want on an horizontal mode (the name at left, a long message in the middle and my avatar at the right of the same row).
But in vertical mode, i have 3 rows, it would be very better to have this organization:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">NAME</div>
    <div class="span6">AVATAR</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since my divs containing `NAME` and `AVATAR` could fit the same row on a vertical mode.

I have many situations like this in my app, What is the best practice in this case ? The only thing i see is to change the div orders with JQuery but i guess there is something better...?

Thanks !

Comment: I think you can create a div to wrap around name avatar and long message , with drop down toggle functionality and display those info when clicked in the small sizes screen

Comment: Yes it's an alternative if i can't change the order properly, i was thinking it could have a specific way to do it.

Comment: can you plz post a screenshot of wat exactly should be your final result.